# PHP Session Issue, not working 100% of the time

Tags: javascript, php, session, appcelerator

I have a really weird issue, the PHP session sometimes returns Undefined index but not all the time. I don't know if anyone has had a similar issue, I haven't changed much regarding session start. I also checked the the available disk space and that seems to be fine for the session data. Has anyone had similar experiences?

```
<?php

session_start();
include_once "security_mobile.php";
include "session.php";
switch($var)
{
 case "get_name":
 echo $securitymob->get_name();
 exit;
}
?>
```

**Security_mobile.php**

```
function get_name(){
 return $_SESSION['customer']['name'];
}
```

This is where the first undefined occurs on customer, then after that it won't work on any others. but sometimes it does work which is what is bugging me!

**Update on issue**

I can fix the issue as soon as I remove this from my app, however I need to get this working.

**connection.js**

```
 var getdb = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload : function(e) {
          var response = this.responseText;
          Ti.App.Properties.setString('tempDB', response);
    },
    onerror : function(e) {
        failed(e);
    },
    timeout : 5000,
    validatesSecureCertificate : false
   });
   getdb.open('POST', this.url, true);
   getdb.send({
        'action' : 'get_name',
        'device' : 'mobile'     
   });
```

could it be to do with return `$_SESSION['customer']['name']`,
the `$_SESSION['customer']['name']` is used within Login stage.

Comment: do you use session_start() on every page? Also, check if you visit a page after a session_destroy()

Comment: Could you add a snippet of your code to demonstrate how you create/handle the session and where the issue occurs?

Comment: i will try and give a readable snippet, just lots of code

Comment: hope that makes some more sense

Comment: Where do you set `$_SESSION['customer']['name']`? Maybe you try to read it before setting it?

Comment: i set his before in the login client, then i run the getdb client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was the HTTP client request was posting to fast, this was not giving time for a connection and session data to be established, hence why results where intermittent. To fix the issue i had to perform the next HTTP client once the first had finished. See this other answer for more details.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39877622/6371663